# How do I ask the Imgur API for a random image by tag?

Tags: node.js, random, imgur

Currently I am trying to find out, if you can ask for pictures by a given tag. Reason is, I am doing a discord-bot via Node.js where people can do commands that will need a random picture, gif by a given topic. Sadly I was unable to find any information on the API Docs that would help me do this task. All I need is an API call that gives me a JSON of either all or (if supported) a random picture given by a supplied tag.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they have really nice documentation in here https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#intro

On initializing your app you could use this structure, make sure you have correct headers in your calls (Authorization: Client-ID YOUR_CLIENT_ID):

1. Check your tags and save them (could be cache, database, file) via

   https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/tag_info/dog

   https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/tag_info/cat
2. Load gallery items and save them under your tags. Don't forget they could be gallery images or albums.

   https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/t/{{tagName}}/{{sort}}/{{window}}/{{page}}
3. When you need an image randomly pick from your cached list and
   return it. Don't forget to remove or disable that item.

   https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/image/{{galleryImageHash}}

Comment: I'm confused on step 2. Where does the 't' come from? I don't see that in the API documentation.

Comment: Since it has been a year maybe they changed the API?